# how can save file with names in utf-8

Tags: python, django, file-upload, utf-8, tastypie

I need to save file with utf-8 names.but when I do it django error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError at /uploaded/document/ 'فیلتر.png'
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 55-59: ordinal not in range(128)
```

although, my filefield like it:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def get_path(instance, filename):
    return u' '.join((u'document', filename)).encode('utf-8').strip()

class Document(models.Model):
    file_path = models.FileField(verbose_name='File', upload_to=get_path,
                                 storage=FileSystemStorage(base_url=settings.LOCAL_MEDIA_URL))
```

how can I fix it?
I use tastypie api to upload file.

Comment: Are you still using Python2? Support is already ended (so do not use it for online application). I think it will difficult for us to remember all tricks about UTF-8 in Python2 (and we cannot test our solution).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenzzi yes, I still use Python2, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my question answered here:
https://itekblog.com/ascii-codec-cant-encode-characters-in-position/#The_Code

I should change apache2 encoding:
/etc/apache/envvars

export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
export LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'